# nsis - How to set VIProductVersion at runtime

Tags: compilation, version, nsis, readfile

I have .ini file that contains a file version (like X.X.X.X). 
So, I used `ReadINIStr` to get the version in 'var' format.

`ReadINIStr $0 "C:\Users\a\Downloads\Info.ini" "Version" "VersionNumber"` 
`StrCpy $varVersion $0`

The above code results in the value of 'varVersion' being stored in the Version in the ini file.

So far, the values I want are well stored.

However, the value to be used for VIProductVersion must be a value using `!define`.

1. Can not use a `variable` other than `!define`?
2. If variable is not available, can I store the value of a particular entry in the ini file in `!define`?
3. I know that the contents of the file can be read using the `!define /file` command. However it is my intent to read only the entry value of the ini file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VIProductVersion` is an attribute stored in your installer .exe and can only be set at compile-time by makensis.

You can use any of the pre-processor instructions like `!define` and `!searchparse` to read/store the version but there is no instruction you can use to read .ini files. `!searchparse` can be used in a pinch if the .ini value name is only used once in the entire file because it does not understand .ini sections.

Comment: And even if variable support was added to VIProductVersion it would not work because you cannot change a .exe file that is running...